# How to upload multiple picked images on firebase storage with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, firebase-storage, imagepicker

I use these firebase function to get data from firestore.

```
static Future<List<String>> uploadFiles(
  List<XFile> images, Reference reference) async {
final List<String> imageUrls = [];
try {
  imageUrls.addAll(await Future.wait(
      images.map((image) => uploadFile(image, null, reference)).toList()));
} catch (error) {
  rethrow;
}
return imageUrls;
```

}

```
static Future<String> uploadFile(
  XFile? image, CroppedFile? croppedFile, Reference reference) async {
UploadTask uploadTask = reference
    .putFile(File(croppedFile != null ? croppedFile.path : image!.path));
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
String imagePath = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

return imagePath;
```

}

and here is where I call the function to be able to have a list of images then uploading them inside a collection in firestore. There are actually as many imagePaths as on the pickedImages links but only one image is visible on image.network others have errors loading with error builder from network image. I don't know what this is due to.`    var user = MyApp.currentUser;
List imagePaths = [];

```
try {
  if (pickedImages != null) {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('residence_images')
        .child(residenceId)
        .child(const Uuid().v4());

    imagePaths =
        await FireBaseStorageMethods.uploadFiles(pickedImages, ref);
  }`
```